# How can I avoid problems coused by '\' character when I write a PATH in Python

Tags: python, path, syntax-error

I was trying to write a code to open applications in windows 10.
I've tested to open a shortcut I copied to C folder as below and it worked:

```
import os

os.startfile("C:\\TheApp.lnk")
```

But when I try it by using another folder which the first character of its name make sense to Python, it gives error as below:

```
import os

os.startfile("C:\\Users\John\3D Objects\VSCODE\ShortCuts\TheApp.lnk")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/John/3D Objects/VSCODE/Test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.startfile("C:\\Users\John\3D Objects\VSCODE\ShortCuts\TheApp.lnk")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\John\x03D Objects\\VSCODE\\ShortCuts\\TheApp.lnk'
```

So when it becomes '\3' or '\v' or something similar it doesn't work.
Can anybody help me?!!

Comment: The backsklash is an escape character, so if you want a single backslash you have to escape it with the escape character (the backslash itself). So either use `'\\'` to have one backslash in the resulting string or use a raw string (like `r'\filename'`) where the escaping rules don't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also might be able to assign the file name as a raw string and pass it to your function.

```py
import os
file = (r"C:\Users\John\3D Objects\VSCODE\ShortCuts\TheApp.lnk")
os.startfile(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for that task i.e. in place of

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\\Users\John\3D Objects\VSCODE\ShortCuts\TheApp.lnk")
```

just do:

```
import os
path = os.path.join('C:\\', 'Users', 'John', '3D Objects', 'VSCODE', 'ShortCuts', 'TheApp.lnk')
os.startfile(path)
```